# How to programmatically create many UIImageViews in a square board

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a type of tic tac toe game in which each square in the board has another smaller game of tic tac toe within it. I am trying to see if there is a way to use a for loop to create these 81 squares, and have them in the correct place.

Comment: better to use collectionview

Comment: What solution have you tried?  There are many ways to tackle this, for example, you can create nested loops smallColumn inside smallRow, inside bigColumn, inside bigRow.  This will give you the opportunity to calculate and place each cell in each game.  Try this and post your code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to create an image programmatically.

```
 let imageName = "yourImage.png"
 let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
 let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
 imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
 view.addSubview(imageView)
```

based on your requirement, use **for loop** and paste the above code in the loop.